# How to fix uneven shoulder blade

Tags: muscle, shoulders

[image]

Hey guys i have this uneven shoulder blade problem for about 3 years .At the beginning i was having issues in tilting the neck to the right side (same side with scapula problem).I was wondering whether the neck tightness is actually due to scapula or the other way around.Due to this my right arm was not able to provide its full potential which causes muscle imbalance on biceps, shoulder and some  back muscles .What can be root cause for these problems.Please pass on some remedies to overcome ?